# How-To Configure Weblogic, Agile PLM and an F5 LTM

Tags: weblogic, f5-big-ip

*Agile, Weblogic, and an F5 walk into a bar ...*

I've got this

- Agile PLM v 9.3
- Running on WebLogic, two managed
  servers.
- An F5 BigIP LTM.

We're upgrading from Agile v 9.2.1.4 running on OAS.

The problem is that while the Windows client works fine the Java client does not.

My setup is identical to one outlined in  F5's doc: http://www.f5.com/pdf/deployment-guides/bea-bigip45-dg.pdf

When I launch the java client it returns this error "Server is not valid or is  unavailable."

Oracle claims Agile PLM is setup correctly, but won't comment on the specifics of the load balancer.   F5 reports the configuration is correct but can't comment on the specifics of the application.

I am merely the guy in a vortex of finger-pointing who wants my application to work.  It's that or give up on WLS and move back to OAS.  Which has it's own problems but at least we know how it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change the Virtual Server type from 'Standard' to 'Performance (Layer 4)'.

From F5:
*A Performance (Layer 4) virtual server is a virtual server with which you associate a Fast L4 profile. Together, the virtual server and profile increase the speed at which the virtual server processes layer 4 requests.*